# Can Mr. Immortal die permanently? (and others with self-resurrection)

Tags: marvel, comics, powers, immortality

Mr. Immortal (Craig Hollis) has the ability of *self-resurrection* and he can resurrect himself endlessly. It is called *resurrective immortality* or *retroactive immortality* also.

> Retroactive Immortality: Mr. Immortal possesses the ability to automatically resurrects and heal from any death he suffers. The resurrection often occurs almost immediately
>
> Deathurge has stated that Mr. Immortal is fated to be live to see the end of the universe.
>
> <sub>http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Craig_Hollis_(Earth-616)</sub>

The main question is:

- Can Mr. Immortal die permanently?

Related questions: Can it be only done by entities like *Death* or *Oblivion*; or only by *One-Above-All*? He is fated to be live to see the end of the universe. Who decides this fate? (Oblivion or One-Above-All?) Could anyone erase or nullify his powers other than *One-Above-All* (considering his fate). (Killing him or his parents via time travel comes to mind also)

Related side questions (that might help with the answer):

- What makes him unique? There are other characters with self-resurrection. (See: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Self-Resurrection.)
  Why is he the only *homo supreme* then? (there are others humans with self-resurrection) Is he the only one fated to be live to see the end of the universe?

---

[image]

<sub>Image Source: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mutants_Classification#Homo_supreme</sub>

Comment: In all fairness, Deathurge says, "No, he has to see the end of the universe," and, being the personification of death and all, I think he knows what he's talking about.

Comment: Can anyone in comics die permanently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at each individual point we can asses this as such:

> Can Mr. Immortal die permanently?

Hes fated to see the end of the world, in that sense he *could* die permanently at some point as his fate is to see the end of the universe, but it doesn't state *which* universe.
As for the Related questions:

> Can it be only done by entities like Death or Oblivion or only by
>   One-Above-All?

Again this comes down to his Fate being to see the end of the universe, therfor if he is able to resurrect then he must have to see his fate through until the end. Also in regards to time travel killing his parents, there are many universes in Marvel and although one would be killed, there will be others to carry on this legacy. Which leads back to the initial question of *which* universe must end.

Hopefully this has helped

Answer (score 0):

Apparently so, when the one below all was unleashed through hulk it was implied he gobbled up mr immortal, Richard Franklin, and then he finally ate Metatron. So yeah, by a being on par with the one above all he can die. Not sure that really helps

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide a reference for when this happened?  You also say it's "implied" he consumed Mr. Immortal; how definite is that?